# How to resolve Youtube Data API v3 : TypeError: response.result.items[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I used the sample code listed on [Youtube Data API v3 - Google Developer's site](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript) in which I went through the authorization process on localhost to load my uploaded videos but nothing shows up afterwards. I inspected the 'response' variable in the console and it was empty string...nothing to tell me what is happening and why the value `response.result.items[0]` is undefined. I checked the other stackoverflow answers with this exact error but none were related to mine such as `playlistId = response.result.items[0].contentDetails.uploads;` had to be `playlistId = response.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;` but am still getting this undefined error in my_uploads.js referenced in the code sample. How do I resolve this?

The only thing I added to the auth.js code was:

`gapi.client.setApiKey('xxxxxxxx');` right before `gapi.client.load`

**my_uploads.js:**

```
// Define some variables used to remember state.
var playlistId, nextPageToken, prevPageToken;

// After the API loads, call a function to get the uploads playlist ID.
function handleAPILoaded() {
  requestUserUploadsPlaylistId();
}

// Call the Data API to retrieve the playlist ID that uniquely identifies the
// list of videos uploaded to the currently authenticated user's channel.
function requestUserUploadsPlaylistId() {
  // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
    mine: true,
    part: 'contentDetails'
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    playlistId = response.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
    requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId);
  });
}

// Retrieve the list of videos in the specified playlist.
function requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, pageToken) {
  $('#video-container').html('');
  var requestOptions = {
    playlistId: playlistId,
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 10
  };
  if (pageToken) {
    requestOptions.pageToken = pageToken;
  }
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);
  request.execute(function(response) {
    // Only show pagination buttons if there is a pagination token for the
    // next or previous page of results.
    nextPageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
    var nextVis = nextPageToken ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    $('#next-button').css('visibility', nextVis);
    prevPageToken = response.result.prevPageToken
    var prevVis = prevPageToken ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    $('#prev-button').css('visibility', prevVis);

    var playlistItems = response.result.items;
    if (playlistItems) {
      $.each(playlistItems, function(index, item) {
        displayResult(item.snippet);
      });
    } else {
      $('#video-container').html('Sorry you have no uploaded videos');
    }
  });
}

// Create a listing for a video.
function displayResult(videoSnippet) {
  var title = videoSnippet.title;
  var videoId = videoSnippet.resourceId.videoId;
  $('#video-container').append('<p>' + title + ' - ' + videoId + '</p>');
}

// Retrieve the next page of videos in the playlist.
function nextPage() {
  requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, nextPageToken);
}

// Retrieve the previous page of videos in the playlist.
function previousPage() {
  requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, prevPageToken);
}
```

Comment: There is no `result` property in the response of [`gapi.client.youtube.channels.list()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) -> `response.items[0]`

Comment: @Andreas Can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: Just read the documentation for the function :)

Comment: @Andreas After reading the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list on `channel.list`, there's no `result` property for this and I used the API Explorer that gave a 200 OK but resultsPerPage and totalResults still remain 0. What am I truly missing?

Comment: As I've already written in my first comment just remove the part with `.result.` -> `playlistId = response.items[0]...` :)

Comment: Sorry if I seem like a noob but do you mean like this, `playlistId = response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;`? If so, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `response.data.items[0]` instead of `response.result.items[0]`.

The type of `response` is `AxiosResponse` (https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts), which has `data` field.